# Why setBackgroundResource() not work in my custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a custom view with the following code :

```
public class TestView extends LinearLayout {
    public TestView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_test, this);
        setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    }

}
```

layout_test.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

It works well, background is black.
But once I added background attribute to xml, setBackgroundResource
not work anymore(layout_test.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

activity_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TestView
        android:id="@+id/testView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[github.com/MummyDing/TestView](https://github.com/MummyDing/TestView)

Comment: in xml layout you have `LinearLayout`, not your custom `TestView`

Comment: where u are using CustomTextview??

Comment: @pskink I modified my question

Comment: @pskink I use the code LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_test, this) to bind my XML&TestView

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? use `hierarchyviewer` to see both views: your custom parent `LinearLayout` and child `LinearLayout` inflated from xml, what do you need them both? (btw you will see that the parent is black and the child is white)

Comment: @pskink My question: (new TestView()).setBackgroundRescoure(R.color.xx) not work.

Comment: have you tried `hierarchyviewer`?

Comment: I tried it before, I can only see one viewgroup: LinearLayout

Comment: so post the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: @pskink I deleted demo project just now, I try to create a new project. please wait.

Comment: @pskink https://github.com/MummyDing/TestView

Comment: so what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

try to use with the help of context

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_test, this).
                setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 public class TestView extends LinearLayout {
        public TestView(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
            setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }

        public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            initView(context);
        }

        private void initView(Context context) {
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_test, this);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an id like:

```
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.my_linear_id);       
lLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color));
```

where **my_linear_id** is the **id** of you **LinearLayout**